# gulp-typescript and outFile option in tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, gulp, asp.net-core, typescript1.6

I'm using gulpfile.js to compile my tsconfig.json project this way:

```
var ts = require('gulp-typescript');

var tsProject = ts.createProject('Modeler/tsconfig.json',
    { typescript: require('typescript') });

gulp.task('build:ts', function () {
    var tsResult = tsProject.src()
        .pipe(ts(tsProject));
    return tsResult.pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/app'));
});
```

It works ok and compiles my typescript files and put js files into wwwroot/app folder

The problem arises then I want TypeScript compiler to output single concatenated file using outFile property

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outFile": "modeler.js"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]  
}
```

The gulp task **does create an empty output file** and creates *.js files with content next to *.ts files.

What should I fix to create desired output file without polluting my source folders?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have external modules in your TypeScript sources?

I've encountered similar behavior in that case. External modules are not allowed when using `outFile` option, but compiler does not complain and emits empty file. Additionally external modules should be emitted "somewhere" (in `outDir`).

If the problem is not about external modules using plain `tsc -p .` behaves the same way as using `gulp-typescript`?

Comment: jquery.d.ts in not external module - it is not problem. The question is whether you use `export` keyword (in .ts not .d.ts). See [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Namespaces%20and%20Modules.md#going-modular) for more details.

Comment: I see, I shouldn't use modules then everything works fine

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using [gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) for this purpose. A Gulp package that does more than one thing goes against the principles of Gulp.

```
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('./lib/*.js')
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's what `--outDir` option of TypeScript compiler is for. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Compiler-Options and please have a look to gulp-typescript [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript) which specifies:

> outDir (string) - Move output to a different (virtual) directory.
>   Note that you still need gulp.dest to write output to disk.

Comment: But how outDir helps me output single file?!

Comment: Your `outFile` should be emitted as before and only the "temporary .js" files should be emitted to `outDir`. So `outDir` should help you get rid of those polluting .js files.

Comment: But my problem is that my output file is generated empty! I need to change smth with it too